# Why isn't my insert data code working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to insert data into a database mysql phpAdmin.

My webhost is 000webhost.

My connection to mysql database code:

```
    <?PHP

$mysql_host = "mysql2.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "*********";
$mysql_user = "********";
$mysql_password = "**********";

$dbcon = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);


if (!$dbcon) {
    die('error connecting to database');
    }
echo ('You have connected successfully');


?>
```

My insert data code:

```
 <?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('connect_mysql.php');

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";

    if (!mysql_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
        die('error inserting new record');
        } // end of nested if statement
        $newrecord = "1 record added to the database";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Data into DB</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Insert Data into DB</h1>

<form method="post" action="insert-data.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
    <legend>New People</legend>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="add new person" />
</form>
<?PHP
echo $newrecord
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of letting me put it into the database it brings me to this page
http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: You don't have `$` sign before the variable names in your query

Comment: u are mixing mysqli_ and mysql fix it first !!

Comment: see my answer to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It DID have to be mysqli

my problem was the - had to be changed to an _ on `<form method="post" action="insert-data.php">`

working code:

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('connect_mysql.php');
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
    die('error inserting new record');
    }
    $newrecord = "1 new record added to the database";
}





?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Data into DB</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Insert Data into DB</h1>

<form method="post" action="insert_data.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
    <legend>New People</legend>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="add new person" />
</form>
<?PHP
echo $newrecord
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try change

```
<label>First Name: <input type="text name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text name="lname" /></label>
```

to

```
<label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
```

and also insert query and connection to

```
$dbcon = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";
```

Comment: yup dude.. its the answer

Answer (score 0):

**First change below code:**

```
$dbcon = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
```

To :

```
$dbcon = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
```

**Then change below code:**

```
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('fname', 'lname')";
```

To:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";
```

Answer (score 0):

can u please change this line?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>New People</legend>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text name="lname" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

to

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>New People</legend>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></label>
</fieldset>
```

you are setting wrong attributes so its not getting the values..

after that, u have to update your sql query:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";
```

Comment: frst of ol, there is no image present there.. so will u please write the exception here ???

Comment: that wasn't an advertising link. READ THE URL IT SAYS ERROR